# Sum expression with IIF clause

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012

I want to sum field called: `Fields!Horas.Value` depending of `Fields!sNombrePlanta.Value`

So I do:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!sNombrePlanta.Value = "AUCHI", Fields!Horas.Value, 0))
```

It work perfectly, but now I want to add another `Fields!sNombrePlanta.Value` and sum this two, so I try:

```
=Sum(IIF((Fields!sNombrePlanta.Value = "AUCHI" And 
Fields!sNombrePlanta.Value = "AUQRO"), Fields!Horas.Value, 0))
```

and it just return blank value. What am I doing wrong there? Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking one field to have two values:

```
=Sum(IIF((Fields!sNombrePlanta.Value = "AUCHI" And Fields!sNombrePlanta.Value = "AUQRO"), Fields!Horas.Value, 0))
```

sNombrePlanta can't have both the values "AUCHI" AND "AUQRO" at the same time. Do you mean to use `OR` where the field is either of those values?

Comment: You're right `OR` is solution of this problem. Thanks!